# How to get the value of an Array of Objects present inside an Array of objects?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

[image: Console.log]

I want to access the Name in the Pricebook2 Object. How to do that in JavaScript? (Salesforce Lightning)

Comment: u shd be able to access it thru normal JSON Object.Property way..

Comment: @VamsiKrishna As I am new to JavaScript, Can you please give me the correct usage to obtain the name on the Pricebook2 Object which is present in the Array of Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete syntax:

```
topLevelArray[0].Pricebook2.Name
```

`[]` is an array accessor

`.` is an object property accessor

Comment: Will this work for Large data sets? Suppose I want to use that value when I am doing some operation like sorting depending on that column what exactly should I do to get all the Pricebook2.Names? Should I loop it and use this?

Comment: Performance is a whole different question.I gave you the basic syntax but you may need to copy these values into a different structure to optimize the way you process your data depending your use case.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for my use case. Below is the implementation:
var total = listOfObjects.length;
var i=0;
var plistName = [];
for(i=0;i<total;i++){
plistName = listOfObjects[i].Pricebook2.Name;
plistName.trim();
}
console.log(plistName);